# How can i solve live search engine error?

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, ajax

I make a simple live search engine using javascript, json, ajax, mysql. Everything i think ok. But when i search something like that - c++, c# it just shown nothing. Please Help me. Here is my code:

`<input type="text" id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your book name..." onkeyup="loadDoc()"/>
<div id="resultView"></div>`

var ajaxRequest;

function ajaxFunction(){

```
 try{

    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

}catch(e){

    try{

        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxm12.XMLHTTP");

    }catch(e){

        try{

            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

        }catch(e){

            alert("Your browser need to update!");
            return false;
        }

    }

}
```

}

function loadDoc(){
    ajaxFunction();

```
manipulateFunction(ajaxRequest);
```

}

function manipulateFunction(xhttp){

```
var searchWord = document.getElementById('search').value;
console.log(searchWord);
var queryString = '?searchString=' + searchWord;
console.log(queryString);
var resultArea = document.getElementById('resultView');

if(!searchWord.replace(/\s/g, '').length){

   resultArea.innerHTML= "Please search something valid...";

}else{

    xhttp.open("GET",'search.php'+ queryString,true);

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){

         if(xhttp.readyState === 4 && xhttp.status === 200){

             var data = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);

             console.log(data);

             if(data.length > 0){

                 var html = "<table border='1px'>";
                 html += "<tr>"
                    html += "<th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Author Name</th><th>Category</th><th>Price</th>";        
                 html += "</tr>";

                 for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){

                     var bookId = data[i].book_id;
                     var bookName = data[i].book_name;
                     var bookAuthor = data[i].book_author;
                     var bookCategory = data[i].book_category;
                     var bookPrice = data[i].book_price;

                     html +="<tr>";
                        html += "<td>" + bookId + "</td><td>" + bookName + "</td><td>" + bookAuthor + "</td><td>" + bookCategory + "</td><td>" + bookPrice + "</td>";  
                     html += "</tr>";         
                 }

                 html += "</table>";

                 resultArea.innerHTML = html;

             }else{

                 resultArea.innerHTML = "Sorry No Result found in our database!";

             }

         }else{

             resultArea.innerHTML = "Waiting for server response....";

         }

    }

    xhttp.send();

}
```

}

```
<?php
 try{
     $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=book_db", "root", "");
     $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

     if(isset($_GET['searchString'])){

        $searchItem = $_GET['searchString'];
```

$query = "SELECT * FROM `book_details` WHERE book_name like '%$searchItem%'";
            $STH = $db->query($query);
            $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

```
        $someData = $STH->fetchAll(); 
        echo json_encode($someData); 
     }

 }catch(PDOException $error){

    echo "<pre>";
        echo $error;
    echo "</pre>";

 }
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

Having just developed a website search function myself using PHP, JSON and Javascript, I would take this sort of action:

a) Are you getting any errors logged in the console when you do the JSON.parse? In my experience a straight json_encode / JSON.parse interaction does not work, because of problems with backslashes and quotes - it may perhaps be ok for your setup, but I found I needed to do this in the php:
echo str_replace('\"','\\"',str_replace("'","\'",json_encode($sqlresultset)));

Also, if the above doesn't help, and apologies if you have already tried all this:

b) Make quite sure that the sql statement returns what you expect when you hard code the search string into it, e.g.:
SELECT * FROM book_details WHERE book_name like '%c#%'

Don't forget about issues with embedded quotes (need doubling), case differences (can't remember whether mysql ignores these).

c) Make quite sure search.php is working as expected when run direct from web browser with appropriate searchString parameter.

d) Code defensively aka 'if it can go wrong, it will go wrong'. So, add some code to search.php to output something suitable when the searchString parameter is /not/ set, rather than just ignoring that situation. Then you will know straight away if your ajax call is somehow sending no parameter string, or is formatting it incorrectly.

Hope some of this helps.

Incidentally, once it's working, I really would recommend you do something to handle potential character set issues - my approach is to transliterate everything to ascii for matching, which does the job without pain & seems to suit my users OK.